# If a machine can be reached via two network interfaces, which one will Windows use?

Tags: windows, networking

Consider, for example, an application server and a storage server.

- Both servers run services which needs to be accessed by everyone, so
  they are connected to the "public" network
- The application server has high IO on the storage server, therefore a dedicated, second network connected just the two of them.

Given that

- Both machines are Windows
- the same machine can be reached via two network interfaces
- the connection is made by machine name rather than IP address

Which connection will Windows use?

---

Bonus question: what if a machine is connected to two separate networks, and two servers with the same name exists on both of them respectively?

Comment: In which name service are the two hosts with the same name configured?

Comment: @Iain Windows machine name. When Network Sharing is turned on, Windows can automatically resolve other Windows machine names to IP on its network even without DNS.

Comment: The machines are in a domain? I had a "similar" setup and the domain subnet was always preferred.

Answer (score 1):

If it's my network, I'm not going to let Windows decide. I'm gonna give the interfaces on the dedicated server-server network different DNS names (maybe application-dedicated and storage-dedicated) and explicitly configure services that need to talk between the servers to use the -dedicated names (or IP addresses if for some reason I can't use DNS names -- like \\dedicated.storage.ip.address\sharename)

Comment: Yes, I know it can be solved by using different DNS name or IP - but my question is, what *if* they're the same name?

Comment: Routing metrics. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/894564 But again, for an "important" connection, I'm not going to let Windows (or any other OS) decide that for me.

Comment: Yes, the routing metrics is the answer I'm looking for. Would you put that in the answer body?